# Case expression with multiple conditions and aggregate functions

Tags: sql-server, case, aggregate

I am looking at a table that has two fields.  One for the height of a case of a particular product and one for the width. Some of the cases are 1X1 for height and width. For the cases that are 1 X 1 I am trying to write a case expression that takes the average of the all multiplied cases width and height and uses that as the new measurements for the 1 by 1.

I have tried a few different case statements here is the first:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN T5.width = '1'
                AND T5.height = '1' THEN (
                SELECT avg(t7.cube) AS AVG_cube
                FROM
                  (SELECT (width*height) AS CUBE
                   FROM TABLE
                   GROUP BY height,
                            width) AS T7
           ELSE (CASE
                     WHEN t5.height > '1'
                          AND t5.width > '1' THEN t5.height
                     ELSE t5.width
                 END)
       END AS AVG_cube
```

The numbers that I am getting from this are way too high. If the width and height aren't 1 then I want to use the numbers that are already there and this is where I am getting hung up. I also tried using just:

```
ELSE T5.width
```

and vise versa with t5.height. I also tried doing the averages seperatly:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN t5.height = '1' then
              (SELECT AVG(height)
               FROM TABLE)
       ELSE t5.height
   END AS height CASE
                     WHEN t5.width = '1' then
                            (SELECT AVG(width)
                             FROM TABLE)
                     ELSE t5.width
                 END AS width
```

However this didn't work because there are instances where height may = 1 but width may = 5. I only need averages when they are both one.

I am using SQL server 2014 and some sample data looks like

```
Height | Width
-------+------
   1   |   12
  12   |    2
  24   |    3
  13   |   12
   1   |    1
```

as far as an answer goes I would be looking for:

```
12 (1x12)
24 (2x12)
36 (3*12)
156 (13*12)
57 (AVG(Width*Height)
```

Comment: Case _expressions_...

Comment: Can you provide sample data, desired results, and the appropirate database tag?

Answer (score 0):

There's some mixed info here, is it avg(widths*heights) as in sample Case statements or avg(widths)*avg(heights) as in sample data for the 1x1 cases?

I think the first case statement you made looks almost finished. After the first case has been evaluated, there are only cases with height > 1 or width > 1, so there's no need to double check

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN T5.width = '1'
    AND T5.height = '1' THEN (
         SELECT avg(t7.cube) AS AVG_cube
         FROM
             (SELECT (width*height) AS CUBE
             FROM TABLE
             GROUP BY height,
             width) AS T7 )
    ELSE T5.width*T5.height -- here are the cases where width or height or both are > 1
    END AS AVG_cube
```